# Slow write speeds with APFS encryped external SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, external-disk, encryption, apfs

I bought an external SSD with a USB 3.1 gen 2 enclosure. I'm on macOS 10.13.6 with a MBP (late 2013).

Using APFS I get write speeds of around 390–405 MB/s. So far, so good.
However formatting the drive to APFS (encrypted) results in way slower write speeds of around 250–260 MB/s.

Is such a performance loss of nearly 40% normal for an encrypted drive, or am I doing something wrong?

I used a 10GB test file and `cp` to measure the performance. Copying through Finder results in similar performance.

Answer (score 4):

According to these benchmarks performances [found here](https://malcont.net/2017/09/apfs-vs-hfs-benchmarks-on-2017-macbook-pro-with-macos-high-sierra/) on APFS, APFS encrypted, HFS and HFS+ encrypted, your loss of nearly 40% may be surprising as you are writing and not reading.

Testing environment summary :

Hardware : 2017 MacBook Pro, 16 GB 2133 RAM

OS : macOS 10.13 High Sierra

[image]

Have you encrypted your already APFS formatted SSD to an APFS encrypted or have you completely reformated your APFS drive to an APFS encrypted ?

If you didn't reformat before your second performance speed test, this may be a cause.

Finally, if you did completely reformat your hard drive, this answer may be interesting :

[Extremely slow write speed to encrypted external drive on Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124231/extremely-slow-write-speed-to-encrypted-external-drive-on-mavericks)

Comment: Hm, but according to those benchmarks only the read speeds of APFS encryped should be significantly slower compared to normal APFS. Write speed should be about the same…

Comment: @M.J.K Indeed, I misunderstood your question. I have edited my answer with a possible answer : `Have you encrypted your already APFS formatted SSD to an APFS encrypted or have you completely reformated your APFS to an APFS encrypted ?

If you didn't reformat before your second performance speed test, this may be a cause.`

Comment: I completely reformatted the drive. I also tried encrypting the already APFS formatted drive but there wasn't any difference. So this shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: @M.J.K, ok, I edited a final time my answer and giving you an other Apple StackExchange link with a similar question of your and its answer. I know it's not a completely full answer and I hope the  community will help, as it surpasses my knowledges !

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I already found that question but it didn't help.

Comment: You're welcome. @M.J.K. I have a question for you, is 40% of loss very grave ? Do you have tons of GB to copy ? If you do have lot to copy, is encrypton really necessary ? I'm looking to the practical side of your question :)

Comment: I will use the drive to (physically) share larger video files and FCPX projects with others. Encryption wouldn't be 100% neccessary, but in case the drive gets lost on the way it would be go to know that someone else can't access the footage/projects.

Comment: Ok, I understand, have you tried to benchmark speed writing performance with HFS instead of APFS ? In case the performance with HFS are better, here are the pros and cons of HFS and APFS : 
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/apfs-vs-hfs-which-apple-filesystem-is-better/

Comment: No I didn't, but I will consider using HFS+ instead. I just figured APFS would be the best option since Apple specifically said APFS will be beneficial for SSDs. Thanks again anyway.

Comment: Yes APFS had to be the best solution as it's consider as the future for MacOS systems, but HFS may be ok, if 40% loss is too much

Answer (score 2):

The problem still exists with a MacBook Pro 2020 running macOS BigSur.

I am using a 2 TB SSD with an USB 3.1 enclosure. The SSD manufacture (Crucial) mentions read / write speeds from 560/510 MB/s in their product information. Tested with several cables and on different ports.

Get around **400/450 MB/s with APFS**:
[image]

Get around **200 MB/s with APFS encrypted**:
[image]

Thats a ~ 50 % difference!

After talking with the Apple Care support they told me that encrypted file formats shouldn't have a huge effect on read / write speed (but as we can see, they do have an effect). They solved a similar problem with another customer by changing the format to the old *Mac OS Extended (Journaled)* one. They have also advised me to ask the SSD manufacture for additional information and help.

Answer (score 2):

Up to `40%` drop is reasonable with the all the overhead of the encryption, it's not for free. However I have found out with the M1 airbook it is also drive dependant.

M1 airbook with a verified dongle (can push 100+ MB):

```
Transcend 1TB: unencryped 100-110 MB/s, encrypted: 40-70 MB/s
Seagate 5TB: unencryped 100-110 MB/s, encrypted: 15-20 MB/s
```

2015 macbook pro (without dongle):

```
Transcend 1TB: unencryped 100-110 MB/s, encrypted: 60-80 MB/s
Seagate 5TB: unencryped 100-110 MB/s, encrypted: 60-80 MB/s
```

As you can see the 2015 macbook trashes the M1 airbook here, but encryption is the key here, because if i create an unencrypted APFS volume, it's pushing `100-110` MB/s.

I noticed `storagekitd` using a lot of cpu on M1.

And I also managed to kernel panic M1 big sur just by connecting an external hard drive with `Suspected bundle: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily.`

This panic has big chance of happening whenever the notebook goes to sleep too:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252421595

USB is very raw on M1.  Let's hope all the panic backtraces I sent will make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I see a drops of 17% (write) and 25% (read) when using encrypted vs non encrypted (One APFS container with APFS Volumes).

It seems that the 40% drop you experience is high in comparison, but it is hard to tell with so little data.

```
APFS Volume type | Write (MB/s) | Read (MB/s)
apfs | 912 | 919
apfs encrypted | 756 | 688
```

Using case-sensitive or not made difference.

Specs:

- OS: `MacOS 10.14.6 Mojave`
- Hardware: `Macbook Pro 2017, 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3 and 2.5 GHz Intel Core i7`
- SSD: `samsumg 970 evo NVMe M.2`
- External enclosure: `sabrent usb 3.1 enclosure for NVMe PCIe M Key M.2 ssd`.

APFS speeds
[image: apfs speeds]

APFS encrypted speeds
[image: apfs encrypted speeds]